# How to make a list of a "@role"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command where, if someone types "?role @testrole", the bot will send an embed with a list of users who have the aforementioned role.

An example response would be:

```
List of @testrole
 - @Adam
 - @Drago
 - @Santiago
```

Here's my code:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'teamone') {
 let team1 = message.guild.member(
  message.member.roles.cache.has('750579457953234994')
 );
 message.channel.send({
  embed: {
   title: 'Team 1 composition!',
   description: `${team1}`,
  },
 });
}
```

I tried but it does not work, it only sends `null`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'teamone') {
 let team1 = message.guild.roles.cache
  .get('750579457953234994') // get the role in question
  .members.map((member) => `<@${member.id}>`) // map the results in mention format (<@${user.id}>)
  .join('\n'); // join by a line break
 message.channel.send({
  embed: {
   title: 'Team 1 composition!',
   description: `${team1}`,
  },
 });
}
```

---

Every `Role` has a [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) property, which is a collection of all (cached) members that have the given role.

You can then use the [`Collection.prototype.map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) function to format each member to a mention. Here's an example from my server:

[image: Example]

(I used the mod role as an example, this is my mod team)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally sent it prematurely, I'm editing in explanation right now

Comment: Holy thanks soo much @Lioness100 u always helped me

Comment: ok, sorry I can't vote I don't have enough reputation 